# Rails ApplicationService for Service Objects has both execute and call. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-object

I've inherited an app that uses a lot of Service Objects, which inherit from `ApplicationService`:

```rb
class ApplicationService
  class InternalServiceError < StandardError; end

  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.execute(*args)
    new(*args).execute
  end

  def self.call(...)
    new(...).call
  end
end
```

Why would there be both an `execute` and a `call` method? It seems odd to have both since they are both instantiating an instance of the class.

Also, what is `(...)` for? I've not seen that argument style before. How is it different to `(*args)` or `(**args)`?

Comment: `...` is used for [argument forwarding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Argument+Forwarding)

Comment: _"they are both instantiating an instance of the class"_ – yes, but each invokes a different method on that instance, namely `execute` and `call`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some internal docs that revealed that `execute` is legacy and with advent of Ruby 2.7 it was decided to replace it with `call`, but nobody has updated the base class to remove `execute`.

Thanks to @Stefan for the [link](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Argument+Forwarding) to explain call forwarding syntax `(...)`